# back ticks not working in perl

Tags: perl

Got stuck with one problem in our live server.

Have script (perl) which runs almost 15 to 18 hrs a day. it creates 100+ sub process every day  . One place it has command (product command which we run in command line solaris box) which is being triggerred with back ticks inside perl code.

It looks like the back ticks command gets skipped or failed randomly.

for eg. if i need to run for 50 customers 2 or 3 gets failed randomly.

I do not see the evidence that the command has been triggerred in anywhere.

since its live server we can't even try making much in code change until we are sure about the problem.

here is the code..

```
my $comm = "inventory -noX customer1"; #sample command i have given here
my $newLogFile = "To capture command output here we have path whre the file gets created");
my $piddy = `$comm 2>&1 > $newLogFile`;
```

Is it because of the back ticks it happens I am really not sure :(.

Also tried various analysis like memory/CPU/diskspace/Adding librtld_db.so in LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc....but no luck...Also the perl is in 64 bit ...what else Can i? :(

Comment: Please post the actual code. Disregarding the syntax error, I doubt that's the name of your log file.

Comment: Here it runs randomly, i mean like alternative days or twice a week it even runs completely without skipping any customers....However it happens with random timing etc....+ its almost 2000+ lines perl code....I am afraid :(

Comment: However its scheduled for daily ....and every day it gets a trigger too...only concern is that we can't predict and the input data also almost similiar ..its just have to trigger the utlity

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are not checking for errors (and perl doesn't make that easy to do correctly for backticks).

Consider using [IPC::System::Simple](http://p3rl.org/IPC::System::Simple#SYNOPSIS)'s capture in place of your backticks/qx.
As its doc says, "If there's an error, it will die with a detailed description of what went wrong."

Comment: Apologies, I am new to perl!!!! Can we use this option in OS - solaris 9 and perl version is v5.8.5...

Comment: You will need to install the module, but it has no other dependencies and purports to work back through 5.6.0, so that should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't fail just because of backticks, however because it is spawning a new process, that process may be periodically subject to failure due to system conditions (eg. sysLoad).  Backticks are really a "fire and forget" method and should never be used for anything critical in a production environment.  As previously suggested, there are far more detailed ways to manage spawning external processes.

If the command's output is being lost due to buffering, you might try turning off buffering, but keep an eye on it for performance degradation (it's usually not significant).

Buffering can be turned off for an entire script by adding this near the top:

```
$|=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling external commands, I'm using **system** of [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.21/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm) or **open3** of [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html).